# Problem installing package from Maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar on Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, installation, package, fullcalendar, laravel-6

### I am using the maddhatter fullcalendar package in my Laravel application

```
composer require maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar

Using version ^1.3 for maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

*Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.*

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar ^1.3 -> satisfiable by maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar[v1.3.0].
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar v1.3.0 requires illuminate/support ~5.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, 
v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, 
v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, 
v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, 
v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.5.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.16|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.17|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.33|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.34|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.35|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.36|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.37|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.39|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.40|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.41|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.43|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.44|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.10|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.11|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.12|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.13|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.14|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.15|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.16|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.17|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.19|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.20|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.21|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.22|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.23|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.24|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.25|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.26|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.27|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.29|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.3|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.30|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.31|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.32|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.33|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.34|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.35|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.36|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.37|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.38|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.39|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.5|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.6|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.7|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.8|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.9|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.10|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.11|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.15|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.20|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.21|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.22|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.23|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.26|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.27|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.3|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.5|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.6|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.7|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.8|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.9|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.11|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.12|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.14|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.15|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.17|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.18|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.19|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.20|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.22|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.24|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.27|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.29|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.3|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.30|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.31|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.32|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.33|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.34|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.35|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.8|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.9|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.2.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.3.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.4.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.30|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.31|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.41|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.19|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.21|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.24|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.25|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.26|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.27|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.31|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.32|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.37|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.43|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.45|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.16|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.23|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.17|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.27|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.36|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.0.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.22|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.25|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.26|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.33|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v6.6.0, required as ^6.2) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.6.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

my problem when i want require maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar, i also try add

"maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar": "~1.0" but have same problem

**Problem 1**
Problem 1
    - Installation request for maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar ^1.3 -> satisfiable by maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar[v1.3.0].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel 6 support wasn't added to that package yet. You can be patient and wait until the developers update the dependencies on that package. Or you can fork it and update their code. It looks like an issue has already been created for Laravel 6 [here](https://github.com/maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar/issues/152).